# Is there a way of expressing the MATHEMATICAL module of an int in C?

Tags: c, math

I mean this | | not this %. 
Like let's say that I've got two integers x and y and and integer z.
Now

```
z = x - y
```

Is there a way to express |z| so that if z is positive it stays positive and if z is negative it's turnt into its opposite? I don't mean to express it with an if, just a mathematical equation, symbol or something like that.

Comment: You mean the absolute value of `z`? Because that [exists in math.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/). Edit: Since you answered positively, I'll post an answer.

Comment: If you want to learn a different language, then please start at the beginning. Either taking on or more classes, or by reading books.

Comment: As for your problem, mathematically it's also called the *absolute value* and searching for that term (together with C) should have given you an answer quite quickly.

Comment: Ok damn, sorry for the dumb question then. I could have just looked it up but in my language we call the absolute value module so when I searched for "module of an int in C" I could find nothing. Thanks anyways! @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Re “CPUs don't have native instructions for that”: The ARMv7 architecture has absolute difference instructions for integers, which provide exactly the `abs(x-y)` the OP seeks and of course provide `abs(x)` by making `y` zero. The Intel 64 and IA-32 architectures have absolute value and absolute difference instructions for integers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, thanks for filling me in. Just learned something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`abs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/) function, provided in the `math.h` header.

Example:

```
z = abs(x - y);
```

Answer (score 1):

If no abs() function, second way (without branching):

```
  int num;

  printf("Enter num: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  printf("Abs=%d\n", num*(1+(num<0)*-2));
```

EDIT after comment from StoryTeller:

The trick works because a conditional test, like "<", returns 0 (for false) or 1 (for true). We can deploy this returned number in a more complex expression. In this case, we want an expression which returns 1 or -1. If the number num is NOT less than 0, i.e. is not negative, "num<0" returns 0 and the expression gives 1+(-2*0) = 1. The number num is returned unmodified. If num IS less than 0, i.e. it is negative, the expression returns -1: 1 + (-2*TRUE), where TRUE's value is 1.

Having now 1 or -1 depending on num being negative, a simple multiplication inverts the sign of num, when needed.

Comment: A word about the mapping you use (`[0, 1] -> [-1, 1]`) will make the answer better, but +1 from me.